# Control number of slides with next/previous buttons in Swiper JS

Tags: swiper.js, sveltekit

I am using [Swiper Maniuplation](https://swiperjs.com/demos#manipulation) effect which shows multiple slides, but when I click next button I want it to append only one slide, not two slides. This is how I integrate it with Svelte:

```
<Swiper
    modules={[Navigation]}
    spaceBetween={20}
    slidesPerView={1}
    navigation
    breakpoints={{
        // >= 640px
        640: {
            width: 640,
            slidesPerView: 1,
        },
        // >= 768px
        768: {
            width: 768,
            slidesPerView: 2,
        },
    }} 
    on:slideChange={() => console.log('slide change')}
    on:swiper={(e) => console.log(e.detail[0])}
>
    {#each reviews as reviewer (reviewer.id)}
        <SwiperSlide>
            <div class="shadow-md">
                {slide.title}
            </div>
        </SwiperSlide>
    {/each}
</Swiper>
```

How do I solve this issue? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

what do you need to append for, isn't it better to do it with Lazy load and load the previous and next one or just one with loadPrevNextAmount (check documentation)?